# having combination of multiple values in datanavigateurlfields in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have binded a datagridview with the database and I am trying to set datanavigateurlfields property.I am able to set value when value directly comes from database,but I wanted to concatenate some constant string like **"edit_profile.aspx+?uid"+[value from database]**,now when I try to add "edit_profile.aspx+?uid" this to the url in double quotes it is treating this string as database column,and when I try to put this value is single quote it gave me parser error.

Here is my code:

```
<Columns>
            <asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="heading"
            datanavigateurlfields="heading"          
            headertext="Title"
            target="_blank"

             />
```

I am trying to concatenate some value with the "heading" in datanavigateurlfields.Please tell me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this....

```
      <asp:gridview id="OrdersGridView" 
        datasourceid="OrdersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false"
        runat="server">

        <columns>

          <asp:boundfield datafield="OrderID" 
            headertext="Order ID"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="ProductID" 
            headertext="Product ID"/>
          <asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="UnitPrice"
            datatextformatstring="{0:c}"
            datanavigateurlfields="ProductID"
            datanavigateurlformatstring="~\details.aspx?ProductID={0}"          
            headertext="Price"
            target="_blank" />
          <asp:boundfield datafield="Quantity" 
            headertext="Quantity"/>

        </columns>

      </asp:gridview>

      <!-- This example uses Microsoft SQL Server and connects -->
      <!-- to the Northwind sample database.                   -->
      <asp:sqldatasource id="OrdersSqlDataSource"  
        selectcommand="SELECT [OrderID], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [Quantity] FROM [Order Details]"
        connectionstring="server=localhost;database=northwind;integrated security=SSPI"
        runat="server">
      </asp:sqldatasource>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

would you pls go through this link [for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx)

OR

```
      <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName], [Address], [City] FROM [Customers]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
            <Columns>           
                 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CustomerID"
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CustomerDetails.aspx?CID={0}"
                     Text="Pass Single Value" />
                   <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City"
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CustomerDetails.aspx?CID={0}&CName={1}&ContactName={2}&Addr={3}&City={4}" // here you are defining values 
                      Text="Pass Multiple Values" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" SortExpression="ContactName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
```